# i want to change page url without page refresh in jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to change url in jquery without page refresh everything is fine but i don't know why its refresh the page.
[livesite](http://staging.moosaconsulting.com/moosaconsulting/)

here is my jquery code

```
$('#menu-custom-menu li a').click(function(){
         var ntext = $(this).text();
            ChangeUrl(ntext, ntext);            
       })
    })
function ChangeUrl(page, url) {
        if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
            var obj = { Page: page, Url: url };
            history.pushState(obj, obj.Page, obj.Url);
        } else {
            alert("Browser does not support HTML5.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because you forgot stop default behaviour of anchors.

```
$('#menu-custom-menu li a').click(function(evt){
         evt.preventDefault();
         var ntext = $(this).attr('href');
            ChangeUrl(ntext, ntext);            
       })
    })
function ChangeUrl(page, url) {
        if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
            var obj = { Page: page, Url: url };
            history.pushState(obj, obj.Page, obj.Url);
        } else {
            alert("Browser does not support HTML5.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can check its live

Comment: Maybe its because you read text value of each link, instead of href attribute. I edited code, read third line and improve your code too.